# C# - Regex for IQN - iqn.yyyy-mm.naming-authority:unique name

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I am new to Regular Expressions and I am trying to parse an IQN with help of Regex.

**The format of the IQN:** iqn.yyyy-mm.naming-authority:unique name

**Example(s):**

iqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi:name999

iqn.2002-07.com.microsoft:dc1-vh2a6.example.com,

iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft:abc.com,

I am able to get the values before **(: Colon)**

**Regex Pattern:** `iqn\.(\d{4}-\d{2})\.([^:]+)`

I want to parse the entire IQN and include the parts after **COLON** as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding text after the colon (any character except comma(,) and colon(:))

```
/iqn\.(\d{4}-\d{2})\.([^:]+)(:)([^,:\s']+)/g
```

Test: [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=iqn%5C.%28%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5C.%28%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B%29%28%3A%29%28%5B%5E%2C%3A%5D%2B%29&i=iqn.1991-05.com.microsoft%3Adc1-vh2a6.example.com%2C%0D%0Aiqn.1991-05.com.microsoft%3Aabc.com%2C%0D%0Aiqn.1998-01.com.vmware.iscsi%3Aname999%2C)

Comment: works but it does not check for the spaces.

/iqn\.(\d{4}-\d{2})\.([^:]+)(:)([^,:\s']+)/g

Works perfectly. Thank you very much

http://refiddle.com/m17e

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Updated the post to include the `\s`.

Comment: According to specification it doesn't support Extended Unique Identifier (EUI)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/iqn\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}(?:\.[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)+(?::.([^,:\s']+))?|eui\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{16}/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Please check http://refiddle.com/refiddles/590720d075622d19c9540000 It selects everything after the end of IQN.

Comment: Updated: 
/iqn\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}(?:\.[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)+(?::.([^,:\s']+))?|eui\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{16}/